# What exactly does this line of code mean?

Tags: c++

I saw this line of code in a source code and I simply can't understand what its meaning is even after having searched around (I don't know what exactly to search for). Can someone explain what this is for or where I can read up on it?

`using f_loadLibraryA = HINSTANCE(WINAPI*)(const char* lpLibFilename);`

Sorry for such a dumb question...

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: Well initially I didn't understand much other than that f_loadLibraryA became an alias of whatever the rest to the right of it is. I don't exactly know what HINSTANCE means, I know that WINAPI* is a pointer to __stdcall and const char* lpLibFilename points to a cstring.

I know a little more now after reading the replys, thanks so much guys. It gives me some ground to do more research. I just didn't understand it at all and had no idea where to start reading about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f_loadLibraryA` becomes a type (almost like a `typedef`) for a function that takes a `const char*` as its single parameter and has a return type of `HINSTANCE`.

`WINAPI` is a `#define` macro that maps to a *calling convention*, which is not part of the C++ standard, but exists to establish how the function should be called (how parameters are loaded onto the call stack, and other low level things like that). It's usually either `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`.

Comment: That makes it much more clearer to me now! Thank you. I still have to read about some stuff like what HINSTANCE is exactly and things like that, but it at least answers this question and gives me a place to start researching.

Comment: "almost like a typedef" - actually, *exactly* like a `typedef`, if I'm not mistaken. `using` supersedes `typedef` in *every* way. It does the same + more. `typedef` is obsolete in modern C++.

Comment: @olawrdhalpme "*I still have to read about some stuff like what HINSTANCE is exactly*" - per [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types): "HINSTANCE: A handle to an instance. This is the base address of the module in memory. HMODULE and HINSTANCE are the same today, but represented different things in 16-bit Windows."

Answer (score 2):

It declares `f_loadLibraryA` to be a type alias for `HINSTANCE(WINAPI*)(const char* lpLibFilename)`.

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias